# How to group benchmark results by method name in BenchmarkDotNet

Tags: c#, benchmarkdotnet

I am trying to output my benchmarkDotNet results as grouped by Method name. Instead it is grouped by Range.

My benchmarks output looks like this:

| Method | Range | Mean | Error | StdDev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FindPrimes | 1000 | 23.377 us | 0.1524 us | 0.1425 us |
| FindPrimesSieveOfEratosthenes | 1000 | 3.140 us | 0.0196 us | 0.0183 us |
| FindPrimes | 10000 | 513.180 us | 0.3876 us | 0.3026 us |
| FindPrimesSieveOfEratosthenes | 10000 | 31.487 us | 0.1408 us | 0.1175 us |
| FindPrimes | 100000 | 12,266.783 us | 90.4759 us | 84.6312 us |
| FindPrimesSieveOfEratosthenes | 100000 | 282.112 us | 3.7559 us | 3.5133 us |

What I want:

| Method | Range | Mean | Error | StdDev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FindPrimes | 1000 | 23.377 us | 0.1524 us | 0.1425 us |
| FindPrimes | 10000 | 513.180 us | 0.3876 us | 0.3026 us |
| FindPrimes | 100000 | 12,266.783 us | 90.4759 us | 84.6312 us |
| FindPrimesSieveOfEratosthenes | 1000 | 3.140 us | 0.0196 us | 0.0183 us |
| FindPrimesSieveOfEratosthenes | 10000 | 31.487 us | 0.1408 us | 0.1175 us |
| FindPrimesSieveOfEratosthenes | 100000 | 282.112 us | 3.7559 us | 3.5133 us |

I was trying to set a custom configuration with orderer but I had no luck so far. Maybe I'm using wrong parameters:

```
var config = ManualConfig.CreateMinimumViable()
.WithOrderer(new DefaultOrderer(SummaryOrderPolicy.Declared, MethodOrderPolicy.Alphabetical))
.AddExporter(exporter); // an csv exporter, removed for brevity

BenchmarkRunner.Run<Benchmarks>(config);
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding this attribute above your class?

```
[Orderer(BenchmarkDotNet.Order.SummaryOrderPolicy.Method)]
```